# String buffer overflow produced by asctime() in C

Tags: c, buffer, overflow, buffer-overflow

I want to print out the time in C using `asctime()`, but when the text gets printed out random charaters are appended after `timeString`. Also, the text `syslog()` prints out in the log file differs from the text printed in the shell by `printf()`. Under the code I've provided the exact output from both outputs. How do I get rid of this behavior? The code is running on a RaspberryPi and I'm logged in via the default macOS terminal.

```
  time_t rawTime;
  time(&rawTime);
  struct tm timeInfo = *gmtime(&rawTime);

  // ...

  char *log;
  char *timeString = strdup(asctime(&timeInfo));

  asprintf(&log, "UTC: %s %.*s Last status: %s. New status: %s.", 
           timeString, 5, "     ", "Hello", "World");

  openlog("httpd-status-notifier", LOG_PID, LOG_USER);
  syslog(logLevel, "%s", log);

  printf("%s\n", log);

  // ...
```

---

**Syslog:**

`Dec 22 17:18:17 rasp httpd-status-notifier[25458]: UTC: Sun Dec 22 17:18:17 2019#012       Last status: Hello. New status: World.`

(Here `syslog` produces `#012`)

---

**Shell (printf)**:

`UTC: Sun Dec 22 17:18:17 2019
       Last status: Hello. New status: World.`

(Here `printf` produces a new line charater)

---

Btw., yes I did notice that `syslog` already logs the date.

Comment: `syslog` uses octal numbers to output control codes (for example, line feed, tab, etc.) as well as whitespace.  `#012` is octal value for line feed, which is displayed as is, by `printf`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: @mangusta thanks! I dumped the content of asctime() and it actually really produces a new line or rather line feed charater at the end. I just have to trim the string at the end :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `asctime()` produces a new line character and this gets represented as the octal ASCII value `012` in the log file as pointed out by @mangusta in the comment section. So trimming the string solves the problem.